# cumulative count(customer_id) for today's date and a number of days leading up to today's date,i.e running sum function in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to sql and hive.Is there any way to get the cumulative count(customer_id) for today's date and a number of days leading up to today's date,i.e running sum function in Hive? The date column in this format:

20120907

I have 2 columns in my dataset, customer_id and date.

There are also partitions in my table and some of the values in the customer_id column are NULL. I am not sure if there are duplicates so I will use

count(distinct(customer_id))
Here is an example of my data.

```
customer_id  date
10001         20140901
10003         20141001
NULL          20150101
10007         20150102
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info. Kindly please post full query if you can that would be great.

Comment: What output do you actually want? Mention an example

Comment: my output should be:

Comment: I need total count of customer ids created till date.

Comment: @Ramya the question still look ambiguous... can you please include the sample input and expected output..

Comment: Hi Anil. we have input as stated in my original query.As an output i need total count of customer ids created till date(running count of customer ids created till date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN customer_id is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) count_all FROM yourTable 
WHERE date <= GETDATE()
```

May be you are looking for this.

Comment: Hi ..I want count(distinct(customer ids)) where customer id value is not all and date_column  is cumulative include today(i.e till date ).-- here i am not sure how to frame the query for cumulative date including today.

Comment: You should provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: I really don't understand what are you going to do, but hope you know. May be you are looking for day-wise customer quantity, if so then try this:
[        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN customer_id is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) count_all, date FROM yourTable 
WHERE date <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC        ]     

What is native language, anyway?